# Display value once per group per page

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have the following 2 nested groups in a simple report.

[image: report 1]

All works ok, except that [ImageUrl] is repeated on every new page in case the second group [FeatureName] has too many entries.

[image: Not needed value]

Is there a way to know the relative page index within a group? This way I can create an expression for `Hidden` property. Or maybe there is another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to split the whole textbox into 2 parts like the following image :

Before split:

[image: before split]

After split:

[image: after split]